# How to compile a third party Java library into a jar file I can use?

Tags: java, api, jar, compilation

I am working with a vendor which provides an API for me to use, and instead of providing a JAR they've given me a folder full of the actual .java classes.

Rather than copy and paste the huge API into my project, how can I compile their folder given to me to include as a JAR in my project in External Libraries?

Their structure follows:

```
com/api/many_supporting_files_and_folders_here
```

which I would basically like to turn into a

```
their_name_api.jar
```

and be able to utilize in my code without having their classes and implementation details available to me.

I am using Intellij IDEA

Comment: Using gradle or maven is highly recommended. You'll also need to work out what dependencies they have - apache commons etc, and set these up in your build script. I'd double check with the vendor though, they must have a build script for internal use.

Comment: Get them to do it. It's their responsibility, not yours. Strange vendor, giving away source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Eclipse, you can just add this "library" as a class folder to your project.

`Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add class folder`.

But as others noted normally the vendor should
pack these into a JAR file and provide the JAR to you.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using eclipse you could use a jardesc file that can archive the classes to a jar.  Go to JAR Packaging Options and point at your jardesc(after setting a destination directory). Hope that helps.